az webapp up returns error "The webapp az204app1099 doesn't exist"
I'm creating my first web app by referring : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/introduction-to-azure-app-service/7-create-html-web-app
This MS page says, 'az webapp up' command will create rg, asp, app.
But I'm getting error on executing step from 'Create the web app' :
az webapp up -g $resourceGroup -n $appName --html

The only difference is, I already have a resource group created and so I first did 'resourceGroup=az204rg' and then ran 'az webapp up command'.
Please help if I'm missing anything in understanding this command.
I also tried using actual names instead of variables but still same error : az webapp up -g az204rg -n az204app1099 --html

Referring to the same MSDoc provided by you, I tried to generate a web application using an existing resource group and the provided sample HTML code directory.
Sometimes, az webapp up may not work as expected due to environment conflicts. Check your CLI environment, version and then try to execute it.
It worked for me as shown below.
$rg = "xxxx"
$app = "mynewjh"
az webapp up -g $rg -n $app --html

Output:



If still the issue persists with the above command, use
az webapp create which is also used to create a web app with Azure CLI.
